# Cannot run NuGet Package Command in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have done this many times with many projects on the same machine, but for some reason the following is not working for me:

1. Add desired DLL (filehelpers in this case) from NuGet package manager
2. Install Costura.Fody (by default it includes Fody 2.0.6; 2.0.7 is available I tried both versions which produced the same result)
3. Use Package Manager Console to run command `Install-CleanReferencesTarget` (copy/pasted from https://github.com/Fody/Costura)

When I get to step three (which has *always* worked up until now) I get the following error:

```
PM> Install-CleanReferencesTarget
Install-CleanReferencesTarget : The term 'Install-CleanReferencesTarget' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-CleanReferencesTarget
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-CleanReferencesTarget:String) [],
                              CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried recreating the project, restarting my PC, restarting VS, running VS as admin, etc but same result. I also verified the DLL in question (FileHelpers.dll) is set to copy local.

I also looked at the `FodyWeavers.xml` file in another project that included the same DLL and didn't have this issue, and that it is identical to the one in this troublesome project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <Costura/>
</Weavers>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening all of a sudden?

Comment: Do you mean that the command line:Install-CleanReferencesTarget can be executed successfully on another project? As a workaround, you can use the target in the project file: <Target 
    AfterTargets="AfterBuild;NonWinFodyTarget"
    Name="CleanReferenceCopyLocalPaths" >
     <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
It seems like the command line is not supported by the NPM, you can also submit this issue here:https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues.

Comment: Correct this is the first time it has not worked. Where exactly do I put that <Target> block? Within the <Costura> tag? That is where I placed it but cleaning/building the solution does not bundle the DLL.

Comment: No, the <Target> block should be put in the your project file (Right click project->unload the project->Edit the .xxproj file).

Answer (score 4):

As per the [latest doc](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/edit/master/README.md), it seems to have been removed in newer versions, which will automatically enable the feature. Clean-up can be disabled by changing the Costura configuration file.

> #### DisableCleanup
>
> As part of Costura, embedded assemblies are no longer included as part
>   of the build. This cleanup can be turned off.
>
> *Defaults to `false`*
>
> ```
> <Costura DisableCleanup='true' />
> ```

See also [this post](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/issues/256) for more details on configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the NuGet Package Management Console (View->Other Windows) and use the command line options, from here: Creating And Publishing A Package[^]
2. Compile this from the source: NuGet Package Project extension[^] (source is here: Home[^])

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, but I've just had the same issue and managed to find a work around.

In the end, rather than use the cmdlet, I added the Target to my proj file from the bottom of [here](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/blob/master/README.md). This seems to have worked.